# Possible to pre-configure Grails plugins from (chained) downstream plugins?

Tags: grails, plugins, grails-plugin

Say I have a `grails-master` plugin that itself contains a (chained) "sub-plugin" called `grails-widget`. The master plugin pulls in the chained plugin like so:

```
// grails-master's BuildConfig.groovy:
plugins {
    compile ':widget:1.0.5' // or whatever
}
```

This way, anytime a Grails app includes `grails-master` as a dependency, both master and chained plugins get pulled in.

Now let's say that the chained `grails-widget` plugin requires configuration. Let's say that if an app requires `grails-widget` directly (sans the master), then one must configure the plugin from inside the Grails app's `Config.groovy` like so:

```
grails.plugin.widget.fizz=1
grails.plugin.widget.buzz='YES'
... etc.
```

Here's what I'd like to accomplish, if at all possible:

- If a Grails app just lists `grails-master` as a dependency, then the master pulls in `grails-widget` **but provides default values** for its `fizz` and `buzz` properties. This way, when the app declares `grails-master`, they do not *need* to define the above properties in its `Config.groovy`.
- Again, if a Grails app just lists `grails-master` as a dependency, then although `grails-master` will (somehow, automagically) provide defaults for `fizz` and `buzz`, the app developer can still choose to define them in their app's `Config.groovy`. In this case, the app-defined values for `fizz` and `buzz` **will override the defaults** set back in `grails-master`.
- Finally if the developer only lists `grails-master` as a dep, it would be nice to allow the app developer to disable the use of the (chained) `grails-widget` plugin altogether. Hence, anything the plugin does at app startup would not occur.

Are these items possible? If so, how could I accomplish them? If not, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes you can accomplish that. Default configs can be added when the master plugin is installed. Manually you can do as a post initialization configuration  in `doWithApplicationContext`. But there is a convenient [**`plugin-config plugin`**](http://grails.org/plugin/plugin-config) which can do that for you. Add this plugin to master plugin and set up default values for the widget plugin. The doc for plugin is self-explanatory. If not, I can add an example.
2. Any config provided by the plugin can be overridden in application's `Config.groovy`. Application's config is initialized in the end (after all plugins are initialized). So you can definitely override the default config which you would have setup from step 1 above.
3. You can `exclude` widget plugin from the master plugin when required, in application's `BuildConfig`.

Example:

```
//BuildConfig in application
plugins {
    compile(':master:0.1') {
        //exclusion based on some logic at build/compile time
        if(some logic satisfied) {
            excludes 'widget'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Awesome** answer @dmahapatro (I'd upvote it if I had the rep) - thank you! One followup question here: in my 3rd scenario (excluding plugins), is there a way to do this programmatically at runtime? Meaning, the Grails app (which use both `grails-master` and the chained `grails-widget` plugins) starts up, uses some logic to decide whether to include or exclude the plugin, and then acts accordingly. Is this possible? If so, how? If not, why? Thanks again!

Comment: @dmahapatro isn't that logic only evaluated at "compile" time not while the application is running?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Correct. My mistake, got carried away with build and runtime. Thanks for rectifying.

Comment: Thanks again @dmahapatro - so is there any way to apply this logic at runtime?

Comment: @Zac No. Plugin inclusion/exclusion is done at the build/compile time. Your other option is to disable the functionality at run time in your app, but you can't exclude it. Disabling it would be something you would need to implement since that means something different for every plugin.

Comment: @Zac I stood corrected. Exclusion will be based on the logic that gets evaluated while the build or installation process for the app. For example, you can check for a particular environment to include the plugin dependency or not.